# Securely send form data instead of using post

Tags: php, html, ssl, web

i have now created a webpage, nothing fancy but it needs to securely send to data to the server, i have read ssl is more secure that GET but have no idea how to implement them

Comment: SO requires you to try first and then ask questions. Your question does not relay any attempts and as such is a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a good question, but you still might look at the following links:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/